# Can I centralize the RoR error into one place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If some user encounter any errors in the application, I don't want to the user see the default error page, for example, routing error, or some others error. How can I show an error page only (for example, an "Error occur", but not showing any errors in font of the user) , and redirect back the user to main page. How can I modify my application to make it suitable?? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, shift into production environment - the stack traces disappear.

If that's not good enough, follow this:

http://blog.aizatto.com/2009/02/06/building-custom-error-pages/

Answer (score 0):

You can shift to production env. You can also change the html and css of the error pages in public folder or over ride the rescue_action_in_public action for ActionPack. Here's a ref. to that: [building custom error pages](http://blog.aizatto.com/2009/02/06/building-custom-error-pages/)